# ggvis is not rendering anything in the viewer pane in RStudio

Tags: r, ggvis

I am not able to get any points when I plot my `ggvis`. Please see my code below:

```r
#install.packages("ggvis", dependencies = T)
#install.packages("shiny", dependencies = T)
#install.packages("htmltools", dependencies = T)
#install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = T)

library(htmltools)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggvis)

mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% layer_points()

#then i get the blank image like below:
```

I am on Windows 10, Rstudio is all up-to-date. I would greatly appreciate your help!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/483

A GitHub issue was opened,please consider leaving your issues in that issue board. I believe r studio team is also aware of this issue.